# SemTech SX126x antenna matching

Tags: impedance-matching, 433mhz, sx126x

SemTech SX126x, LLCC68. Please, I could not find the component values for a matching antenna at 433 MHz and +22dbm. Do you have a schematic and list of nominal values for this? I was only able to find an evaluation kit with the 868MHz setting.